# Service Fabric and Entity Framework Migrations

Tags: entity-framework, azure-service-fabric

I'm using Service Fabric with Entity Framework 6.1.3 . When I try to enable migration with 'Enable-Migrations' I have the error:

```
Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s): "Type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.Automation.OAProject' in assembly 
'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation, Version=14.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable."
At C:\repos\Gsa.Pops.Bookings\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:720 char:5
+     $domain.SetData('startUpProject', $startUpProject)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SerializationException

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetProjectTypes(Project project, Int32 shellVersion)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.IsWebProject(Project project)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.GetFacade(String configurationTypeName, Boolean useContextWorkingDirectory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.FindContextToEnable(String contextTypeName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I suppose that EF cannot find the connection string because the starting project is a Service Fabric Application (so no web.config but an ApplicationManifest.xml and multiple environment configurations)

Any clue?
Thanks,
Alberto

Comment: I don't know if it will work, but try to set the project with migrations as a startup project.

Comment: Finally I did it as netchkin suggested. My "infrastucture" project (the one with dbcontext and migrations) is the start up project. The only backdraw is that I have to manually copy the connection string in the app.config of this project (the connection string is different depending of the environment I'm working on)

Answer (score 1):

You could store your connection strings in the KeyVault in Azure, and then have your infrastructure project pull from there.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following command to enable the migration,
Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations -ProjectName <Project Name where migration folder will include> -StartUpProjectName <project name where connection string exist>